# Did Newton conduct any experiments to find something called momentum, or was he such a great genius that he was able to spot it intuitively?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, history

I wanted to go to the depth of the discovery of classical mechanics, instead of just reading, accepting and learning things. Now my question is not a single question, but it can answer many of my doubts. I completely understand motion, but I got stuck with forces.
First, I want to tell all the physicists out there that I have read many books in which while describing momentum, they simply write that it is $m*v$, or they give this proof that I am not able to understand:

> $p \varpropto m$
>
> $p \varpropto v$
>
> So $p = Kmv$, where K is constant of proportionality.
>
> By experiments, it was found that value of k is 1.
>
> So $p = mv$;

- Now I don't know what kind of magical experiments they talk about while saying that $k = 1$. So, first question: Can someone explain this proof to me?

After long searching, I found a book which talked about a very unique experiment and drew a table of values for it, and before telling Newton's second law, they told that a pattern exists within the table, and that pattern was that $m*v$ in every trial was the same, with which I completely agree, and they told that this $m*v$, which remains conserved, is defined to be momentum, for easier equations. Then through momentum conservation, they came out to the fact that $F = ma$, which was completely intuitive and I moved on.

- But, (now moving to my original question) , the equipment's used in that experiment were very new, they didn't existed in Newton's period(example light gates), or did they?
- So my second question: How did Newton came to the fact that $m*v$ remains conserved, or simply this pattern exists?
- Did he conducted any experiments?
- If yes, then what were they? If no, then how he led to momentum conservation?

Now my final doubt. There are many concepts in physics which include a constant of proportionality, and books just throw their values, instead of telling how these values were found.

- So how do these constants were found?

Can someone please tell me just the method which is used to find the value of $k$ in my first question? It will be enough to satisfy me. I have asked many questions about this, but never got the answer which was intuitive.

Note: I request the readers to not give answers involving calculus, because I don't understand it right now, I will study it in the future.

Comment: This might be more appropriate at [hsm.se] than here.

Comment: The problem here is about definitions. I personally would *define* momentum as the product of mass and velocity, and therefore avoid the "k" problem altogether. Your book calls momentum something else, and THEN proves it happens to be equal to m*v. Now, what was this "something else"? Try to understand this first.

Comment: What a great question! Finding proportionality constants is all about doing controlled experiments where you measure all other values than the constant itself. If you know that F is proportional to a, then you know that F=ma where m is some proportionality constant. Then do an experiment where you know both F and a (use a Newton meter to measure a force and a meterstick plus a timer to measure an acceleration). Then you just plug F and a into the expression and find m. And then you do that many times to settle it.

Comment: Historically speaking there was a notion of *impetus* before this, which Descarte for example took to be conserved *a priori*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### K=1

The value of K was arbitrarily defined. Actually as momentum was to be defined here, Newton had a freedom of choosing any constant *except 0*. He could have chosen it to be **2** but that would make the calculations difficult as compared to **K = 1**. This is what gives you the definition of momentum as mass times velocity. In case Newton would have chosen it to be **2**, your definition would have been twice of mass times velocity.

### Experiment

Actually Newton's second law is **(F)(∆t) ∝ (m)(v)**. This was what was experimentally found by Newton by changing one of the parameters while the others remained fixed.

He used

1. Meter scale
2. Stopwatch
3. Glass Surfaces to *reduce friction*

### Conservation of momentum

This quantity of (m)(v) was defined as a new thing called ***Momentum***. Now if ***F*** remains zero then *(m)(v)* doesn't change and hence momentum remains conserved.

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that Newton used metersticks and stopwatches before either were invented.

Answer (score 0):

Newton was not the first to devise or discover the concept of momentum. This goes at least as far back as [Fr. Jean Buridan](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/Jean_Buridan.aspx#1) (ca. 1295 - ca. 1358), professor of natural philosophy and rector of the University of Paris, who was the first to introduce the [*impetus* theory of projectile motion](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/3686). See [this translated excerpt](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/3686) from his *Quaestiones super octo physicrum libros Aristotelis*.